# Delphi - Proxy Design Pattern - interface problem

Tags: delphi, oop, design-patterns, interface

Hi 
I am trying to do design patterns in Delphi and, since I couldn't find a reference material that I like in Delphi, I am converting the patterns I have in the O’Reilly C# 3.0 Design Patterns book. But this is not the problem. I have created the Proxy pattern from this book but there are some concepts of Delphi interfaces, constructors and destructor and general object lifetime and behavior that I apparently don't understand.
First I will post my code:

```
unit Unit2;  

interface  

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  ISubject = interface
  ['{78E26A3C-A657-4327-93CB-F3EB175AF85A}']
  function Request(): string;
end;

  TSubject = class
  public
    function Request(): string;
    constructor Create();
  end;

  TProxy = class (TInterfacedObject, ISubject)
  private
    FSubject: TSubject;
  public
    function Request(): String;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

  TProtectionProxy = class (TInterfacedObject, ISubject)
  private
    FSubject: TSubject;
    FPassword: String;
  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    function Authenticate(supplied: String): String;
    function Request(): String;
  end;

implementation

{ TSubjectAccessor.TProxy }

destructor TProxy.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(Self.FSubject) then
    FreeAndNil(Self.FSubject);
  inherited;
end;

function TProxy.Request: String;
begin
  if not Assigned(Self.FSubject) then begin
    WriteLn('Subject Inactive');
    Self.FSubject := TSubject.Create();
  end;
  WriteLn('Subject active');
  Result := 'Proxy: Call to ' + Self.FSubject.Request();
end;

{ TSubject }

constructor TSubject.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function TSubject.Request: string;
begin
  Result := 'Subject Request Choose left door' + #10;
end;

{ TProtectionProxy }

function TProtectionProxy.Authenticate(supplied: String): String;
begin
  if (supplied <> Self.FPassword) then begin
    Result := 'Protection proxy: No Access!';
  end else begin
    Self.FSubject := TSubject.Create();
    Result := 'Protection Proxy: Authenticated';
  end;
end;

constructor TProtectionProxy.Create;
begin
  Self.FPassword := 'Abracadabra';
end;

destructor TProtectionProxy.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(Self.FSubject) then
    FreeAndNil(Self.FSubject);
  inherited;
end;

function TProtectionProxy.Request: String;
begin
  if not Assigned(Self.FSubject) then begin
    Result := 'Protection Proxy: Authenticate first!';
  end else begin
    Result := 'Protection Proxy: Call to ' + Self.FSubject.Request();
  end;
end;

end.
```

These are the interfaces and classes used in the pattern. Next, is the code that uses these types:

```
program Structural.Proxy.Pattern;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas';

var
  subject: ISubject;

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;

  try
    WriteLn('Proxy Pattern' +  #10);

    try
      subject := TProxy.Create();
      WriteLn(subject.Request());
      WriteLn(subject.Request());

      subject := TProtectionProxy.Create();
      WriteLn(subject.Request());
      WriteLn(TProtectionProxy(subject).Authenticate('Secret'));
      WriteLn(TProtectionProxy(subject).Authenticate('Abracadabra'));
      WriteLn(subject.Request());

      ReadLn;      
    finally

    end;

  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Is it legal to just assign a new object instance against an interface variable? I see in debugging that the constructor for TProtectionProxy is executed first and then a destructor for TProxy.
After the TProtectionProxy is created, Authenticate('Abracadabra') should be validated in logic but in debugger the FPassword is empty while it was assigned in the constructor? This one is very puzzling. But when I close the application, in the destructor, the password is present?
TProtectionProxy(subject) is ok but I read that is not recommended but (subject as TProtectionProxy) was not compiling for some reason (Operator not applicable...)?
I have added destructors because of the FSubject field. Is that ok?
Can a field variable be initiated on the same line where it is declared or I need to initiate in the constructor like in TProtectionProxy?

I know it is a lot I am asking here but I don't know anyone personally who knows Delphi OOP so well that I can ask.

Thank you.

---

This is the new version that works well for me. Thank you for all your help.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  ISubject = interface
  ['{78E26A3C-A657-4327-93CB-F3EB175AF85A}']
    function Request(): string;
  end;

  IProtected = interface
  ['{928BA576-0D8D-47FE-9301-DA3D8F9639AF}']
    function Authenticate(supplied: string): String;
  end;

  TSubject = class
  public
    function Request(): string;
  end;

  TProxy = class (TInterfacedObject, ISubject)
  private
    FSubject: TSubject;
  public
    function Request(): String;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

  TProtectionProxy = class (TInterfacedObject, ISubject, IProtected)
  private
    FSubject: TSubject;
    const FPassword: String =  'Abracadabra';
  public
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    function Authenticate(supplied: String): String;
    function Request(): String;
  end;

implementation

{ TSubjectAccessor.TProxy }

destructor TProxy.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FSubject) then
    FreeAndNil(FSubject);
  inherited;
end;

function TProxy.Request: String;
begin
  if not Assigned(FSubject) then begin
    WriteLn('Subject Inactive');
    FSubject := TSubject.Create();
  end;
  WriteLn('Subject active');
  Result := 'Proxy: Call to ' + FSubject.Request();
end;

{ TSubject }

function TSubject.Request: string;
begin
  Result := 'Subject Request Choose left door' + #10;
end;

{ TProtectionProxy }

function TProtectionProxy.Authenticate(supplied: String): String;
begin
  if (supplied <> FPassword) then begin
    Result := 'Protection proxy: No Access!';
  end else begin
    FSubject := TSubject.Create();
    Result := 'Protection Proxy: Authenticated';
  end;
end;

destructor TProtectionProxy.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FSubject) then
    FreeAndNil(FSubject);
  inherited;
end;

function TProtectionProxy.Request: String;
begin
  if not Assigned(FSubject) then begin
    Result := 'Protection Proxy: Authenticate first!';
  end else begin
    Result := 'Protection Proxy: Call to ' + FSubject.Request();
  end;
end;

end.
```

and the program code:

```
program Structural.Proxy.Pattern;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas';

var
  subject: ISubject;
  protect: IProtected;

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;

  try
    WriteLn('Proxy Pattern' +  #10);

    try
      subject := TProxy.Create();
      WriteLn(subject.Request());
      WriteLn(subject.Request());

      subject := nil;
      subject := TProtectionProxy.Create();
      WriteLn(subject.Request());
      if Supports(subject, IProtected, protect) then begin
        WriteLn(protect.Authenticate('Secret'));
        WriteLn(protect.Authenticate('Abracadabra'));
      end;
      WriteLn(subject.Request());
      ReadLn;      
    finally

    end;

  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I have removed all the constructors cause now they really don't do anything. And the default parametherless constructors are inherited from TInrefacedObject, correct?
I have left Self, I would like to hear why this shouldn't be used?

thank you

I have the full pattern implementation on http://delphipatterns.blog.com/2011/02/22/proxy-2/

Comment: Some quick tips: Don't use `Self.` unless you need to. Don't test Assigned() before you call `Free` (or `FreeAndNil`), Free works with a `nil` reference. Always call `inherited;` in your constructors. Yes you assignment to `subject` of the result of an object construction is the right way to do it. But don't attempt to cast an interface to an object. If you want to call `Authenticate`, expose it through an interface.

Comment: The reason not to test <> nil before Free id that Free effectively says `if Self <> nil then Destroy;`

Comment: The reason I was using Self is to reference the correct FSubject field for a class. Shouldn't I do this?  
I thought that Assigned should be used like this. If the variable is not assigned there is not need to FreeAndNil or Free it?
@Garry: I'm sorry I don't really understand what you are saying here? Can you give more details please? I guess this is related to my not understanding the destructors and Free and FreeAndNil

Comment: @David Heffernan and @Garry: this is just so you would be notified of my comment. Thank you

Comment: @elector If `obj=nil` then you can call `obj.Free` and `FreeAndNil(obj)` safely because the `if Assigned(obj)` test is performed by `TObject.Free`. Your code is correct, just too verbose. Likewise with `Self`. This is not Python. You can omit the `Self` and it will be implicitly inferred. You would only need it if you had a local variable of the same name which took your field out of scope.

Comment: @David Heffernan: So using Self is not actually wrong. But it can be omitted?
And the testing for freeing the variable should be done with if obj=nil then FreeAndNil(obj) ? Or should I use obj.Free? Or Free(obj)? I never learned the difference and what is the best practice. 
Cause what i would like to lear is the best practices here.
Thank you David.

Comment: @elector Best practice: `Self` is optional, omit it unless there is ambiguity, even better: try to avoid ambiguity! Never test for `Assigned(obj)` before calling free. Write `FreeAndNil(obj)` instead.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you. I agree on the ambiguity. Can I call FreeAndNil(obj) if obj = nil? 
And can you please give a small explanation of when to use Free(obj), FreeAndNil(obj) or obj.Free?

Comment: @elector Yes you can call `FreeAndNil(obj)` if `obj` is `nil`. I always call `FreeAndNil` rather than `Free` because it means that any erroneous accesses of `obj` fields after it has been freed will definitely raise exceptions. If you just call `Free` then such erroneous accesses might work, but then fail when the program runs on your client's machine!

Comment: @David Heffernan: I always use FreeAndNil as well. So let's sum up: the best practice for freeing objects is to check obj = nil and if not then FreeAndNil(obj)?
Thank you for all your answers David

Comment: @elector No, best practice is **not to check** and just call `FreeAndNil(obj)`. You simply don't need to check for `nil`. Did I not make that clear in my wording?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Sorry, I didn't understand it that way. But I accept your instructions. So FreeAndNil will not throw an exception when called on obj that is nil?

Comment: @elector No it will not throw. `Free` is implemented as `if Self <> nil then Destroy;` and `FreeAndNil` calls `Free` so inherits the same protection. This design decision was taken to allow destructors to run on partially constructed objects, e.g. where an exception is thrown during a constructor.

Comment: Late back here as @elector had my name wrong. I would ignore David about using FreeAndNil rather than Free. I only use it if I need to check if an object still exists at a later point. It can be dangerous as the Delphi compiler won't give `[DCC Warning] Unit3.pas(30): W1036 Variable 'o' might not have been initialized` warnings in cases where `o.Free;` will. While I have a lot of respect for David, I consider the automatic use of FreeAndNil to be a bit cargo-cultish

Comment: @Gerry Sorry for misspelling your name. I agree that '... might not have been initialized' is a useful warning. Same as Gerry, @David, respect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not saying what version of Delphi you are using. The code you have given is only valid in Delphi XE and produces the following (correct) output there:

```
Proxy Pattern

Subject Inactive
Subject active
Proxy: Call to Subject Request Choose left door

Subject active
Proxy: Call to Subject Request Choose left door

Protection Proxy: Authenticate first!
Protection proxy: No Access!
Protection Proxy: Authenticated
Protection Proxy: Call to Subject Request Choose left door
```

If you look at the generated machine code:

```
Project2.dpr.25: WriteLn(TProtectionProxy(subject).Authenticate('Secret'));
004122C2 A1788E4100       mov eax,[$00418e78]
004122C7 8B154CF84000     mov edx,[$0040f84c]
004122CD E8E22BFFFF       call @SafeIntfAsClass
004122D2 8D4DE0           lea ecx,[ebp-$20]
004122D5 BA38244100       mov edx,$00412438
004122DA E875D9FFFF       call TProtectionProxy.Authenticate
004122DF 8B55E0           mov edx,[ebp-$20]
004122E2 A1EC3C4100       mov eax,[$00413cec]
004122E7 E8BC24FFFF       call @Write0UString
004122EC E82F25FFFF       call @WriteLn
004122F1 E82A1CFFFF       call @_IOTest
```

You can see how the compiler first generates a call to SafeIntfAsClass which is used to get from an ISubject pointer to a pointer for the object that is implementing ISubject. Then TProtectionProxy.Authenticate is being called with this (correct) Self pointer.

If you try to run the same code with older versions of Delphi, this will fail:

```
var
  subject: ISubject;
begin
...
      subject := TProtectionProxy.Create();
      WriteLn(subject.Request());
      WriteLn(TProtectionProxy(subject).Authenticate('Secret'));
```

Older versions of Delphi did not support safely casting from an interface back to an object. What happens then is that the compiler simply takes the value of the subject variable, and calls TProtectionProxy.Authenticate with it.

The call itself succeeds because TProtectionProxy.Authenticate is a simple static method, not a virtual method, so the compiler just generates a call to an absolute address for it. But inside TProtectionProxy.Authenticate, Self is then wrong. Because the subject pointer is different from the object pointer for the TProtectionProxy that's implementing ISubject.

The correct solution for older delphi versions is to introduce an additional interface:

```
type
  IProtection = interface
    ['{ACA182BF-7675-4346-BDE4-9D47CA4ADBCA}']
    function Authenticate(supplied: String): String;
  end;
...
  TProtectionProxy = class (TInterfacedObject, ISubject, IProtection)
...

var
  subject: ISubject;
  protection: IProtection;
...
      subject := TProtectionProxy.Create();
      WriteLn(subject.Request());
      if Supports(subject, IProtection, protection) then begin
        WriteLn(protection.Authenticate('Secret'));
        WriteLn(protection.Authenticate('Abracadabra'));
      end else
        WriteLn('IProtection not supported!');
      WriteLn(subject.Request());
```

Generally speaking, you should never mix object and interface based access. Once you got an interface reference to an object, you shouldn't keep any object references to it (because the object will get automatically freed whenever the last interface reference goes out of scope somewhere). And even though Delphi XE allows you to correctly cast back from an interface to an object, that is something you should use very very carefully.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten. This was very useful. I am using Delphi 2007. And, as I said, I am trying to make C# design patterns work in Delphi. I like the Interface usage. And the fact that Delphi does reference counting. I think programming agains interfaces is very useful. But I had no idea that Delphi handle's it this way. No it is much clearer.

Comment: On the general topic of interfaces, you might find the following e links quite useful: http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=intf-fundamentals http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=intf-advanced http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=intf-aggregation

Answer (score 2):

Is it legal to just assign a new object instance against an interface variable?

- Yes. More than that, it is the right way to use interfaces in Delphi.

I see in debugging that the constructor for TProtectionProxy is executed first and then a destructor for TProxy.

- Does it make any change for you? That is implementation details.

If you want to destroy TProxy object first assign subject to nil:

```
  subject := TProxy.Create();
  WriteLn(subject.Request());
  WriteLn(subject.Request());

  subject := nil;
  subject := TProtectionProxy.Create();
  ..
```

After the TProtectionProxy is created, Authenticate('Abracadabra') should be validated in logic but in debugger the FPassword is empty while it was assigned in the constructor? This one is very puzzling.

- I don't see it. FPassword is assigned as it should be.

But when I close the application, in the destructor, the password is present?

- that is because subject is global variable. You can assign it to nil to force the object destruction manually before calling readln:

  Subject:= nil;
  Readln;

TProtectionProxy(subject) is ok but I read that is not recommended but (subject as TProtectionProxy) was not compiling for some reason (Operator not applicable...)?

- I don't understand what are you trying to do. Both TProtectionProxy(subject) and (subject as TProtectionProxy) code does not seem sound.

I have added destructors because of the FSubject field. Is that ok?

- Yes, you should destroy FSubject object instance in the destructors.

Can a field variable be initiated on the same line where it is declared or I need to initiate in the constructor like in TProtectionProxy?

- No, you should initiate FPassword in the constructor as you did.

If you are not going to change FPassword you can declare it as constant:

```
  TProtectionProxy = class (TInterfacedObject, ISubject)
  private
    FSubject: TSubject;
    const FPassword: String = 'Abracadabra';
  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    function Authenticate(supplied: String): String;
    function Request(): String;
  end;
```

And don't use `Self` - there is no need for it in your code.

Comment: Thank you Serg. I could, in fact, use const for the password field. 
I know that in .net it is legal to cast an interface variable to an object, that's why I have assumed that it is legal in Delphi as well?
I don't really understand these suggestions not to use Self? I thought that this is a legal way of making sure that, in my example, the variable FSubject belongs to the correct class, the one that it is currently used?
Thanks again

Comment: @Serg: this is only so you would be notified of my previous comment. I just read the instructions :)

Comment: In your code there is a lot of "Self." You can do a search and replace "Self." to "" without changing the functionality of the code.

Comment: @Thorsten Engler: I will definitely remove the Self cause I see no one likes it :). I though it is a good practice in OOP.

Comment: @elector What language do you normally code in? I'm guessing something like Python where the use `self` is essential.

Comment: @Thorsten Engler: I do .net in C#. It is not mandatory I just thought it is a good practice cause I want to make these pattern examples good and maybe make them public for people who want to learn them in Delphi. Maybe put them on codeplex where people can contribute and improve them. That is why I wanted the include all the best practices I know of. 
Thank you for your input.